# Excel change column format and name

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am fighting to code in VBA Excel. I have .xlsx file which I am successfully able to convert into .csv. The excel file has 12 sheets and I am trying to save sheet named "Data" before converting it to .csv. Also before I save this sheet in .csv I need to change column format to Date and change its name. The code is working well except I am not getting column name and column format changed. What am I doing wrong? I tried this:

```
Dim saveSheet As Worksheet

'Save only sheet named Data among all 12 sheets
Set saveSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

'Save column N as Date format
saveSheet.Application.Range("N2", "N50000").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"

'Change column name to Ship Date
saveSheet.Application.Range("N1").Value = "Ship Date"

'Save file in .csv
saveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFolder & "\" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Drop the `.Application`: `saveSheet.Range(...)`

Comment: @BigBen it worked! thank you so much for the quick response.